# FOC greater than 0

Tags: consumer-theory, self-study

I couldn't get my head around this part. Basically, I have to prove that a consumer has to hold a positive amount of assets, i.e. $x > 0$.

A hint suggested to find take the FOC, and then set $x = 0$ and I would see that FOC is greater than 0, meaning that $x = 0$ cannot possibly be a utility maximizing choice, and the consumer must hold a positive amount of assets.

What does FOC being greater than 0 have anything to do with $x = 0$ not being the a utility maximizing choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not quite possible to have "FOC greater than 0", since the FOC is a *condition*, not a number. What is really meant here is the derivative of the utility function.

If your utility function is given by $u(x)$, then the FOC for a maximum would be $u'(x)=0$. Now if you calculate the derivative $u'(x)$ and then substitute $0$ for $x$, then you get the derivative at $0$, written $u'(0)$.

If it turns out that $u'(0)>0$, then this means that your utility function is *locally increasing* at $0$. Hence, if you increase $x$ a little bit, starting from $0$, then your utility also increases. Therefore your utility function cannot have a maximum at $0$. Rather, its maximum must be attained at some positive $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Remember what is the **goal of optimization**: It is to find some maximum or minimum of a function. Potentially, to find maximum or minimum such that something must be satisfied (constraints)

First order conditions tell you that the directional slopes (partial derivations) of function are $0$. If you think about it, slope being equal to $0$ indicates local maximum or minimum (the function either stops increasing or decreasing).

Now, usually the result of taking FOC of some problem results in **functions** (or **conditions** that must hold for a choice to be optimum), let's call them $f'(\boldsymbol{x}) = 0$. If you plug concrete numbers into $\boldsymbol{x}$, for example $x = 0$, and with that your $f'(\boldsymbol{x}) \neq 0$, you know that the condition resulting from FOC **cannot be satisfied by that concrete** $\boldsymbol{x}$!

Only such choice $\boldsymbol{x}$ for which it holds $f'(\boldsymbol{x}) = 0$ can be optimal!

Comment: This is not really true since it ignores the possibility of a boundary maximum. $f$ could be strictly decreasing.

Comment: Could you elaborate further? When doing Lagrangian (or KKT when necessary), even boundary maximum requires that $f'(\boldsymbol{x}) = 0$, where $f$ is the Lagrange function.

Comment: The $f$ you describe in your answer is defined on "numbers" $x$ and has a derivative denoted by the prime. This cannot be a Lagrange function.

Comment: It's more of a notation thing (by the way, the $x$ is bold in my text). If you read the text, you can see that I speak of conditions or functions and I just denote them by $f'()$. The $\boldsymbol{x}$  is vector of variables, not single "numbers", that is why it is bold. What concerns the rest, the $f'(\boldsymbol{x})$ is a vector of FOC. Just a reminder that I consider the multiplicator to be variable as well.

Comment: O.k., but then the prime in $f'({\bf x}) \ne 0$ has to be interpreted as a gradient and the $0$ as the zero vector. And this while the problem of the OP is obviously 1-dimensional...

Answer (score 0):

If the question asks you to prove $x>0$, then the easiest you can do is to come up with the contradiction. Take $x=0$ and some $x>0$, show that the utility $u(x>0) > u(x=0)$. You are done.

Analytically, you could investigate your utility function. If it is increasing monotonically in $x$, then $x$ is going to hit the maximum possible constraint, unless you have a constraint that imposes exogenously $x=0$.